# Changing opacity in DIV

Tags: css

I have the menu, the sample code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span id="header1" class="menu_header">WELCOME</span></a>
        <!--Submenu-->
        <div id="sub_backbone"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`#header1` this title menu, `#sub_backbone` this tab is the default transparent

```
div#sub_backbone{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I need to **hover on the WELCOME, #sub_backbone opacity changed to 1**.

Comment: I have a problem. When I am bringing to the header menu tab is displayed, but I need more so I can put things on the tab. But when I am bringing mice tab it disappears. What can I do for solving this situation? The code: 
div#menu ul li a:hover > #sub_backbone,
div#menu ul li a:hover > #sub_backbone_center,
div#menu ul li a:hover > #sub_backbone_end{
    opacity: 1;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not that hard...

You have to use `hover`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xbMtN/3/

```
div#sub_backbone:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Edit, I see you changed your question. Here you go:

```
ul li:hover > div#sub_backbone { 
    opacity: 1;
}

div#sub_backbone{
 opacity: 0.3;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xbMtN/4/

Comment: div#menu ul li:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}not working, because I need to hover the mouse on "Welcome" appeared #sub_backbone

Comment: This works but the problem when I am bringing to the tab that should be hidden "asfasffaa" it appears. See my example. And I need so I can put things on the "Welcome" and asfasffaa appeared, I could go to him and he will not fade.

Answer (score 1):

You should use sibling selector `+`:

```
li a:hover + #sub_backbone {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N8ghp/

Support: [IE8+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2).